# Generate SQL Scripts from MSSQL 2005 (Including Data)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Title says it all really, whats the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [**Microsoft's SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en):

> SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard
>   enables the deployment of SQL Server
>   databases into a hosted environment on
>   either a SQL Server 2000 or 2005
>   server. It generates a single SQL
>   script file which can be used to
>   recreate a database (both schema and
>   data) in a shared hosting environment
>   where the only connectivity to a
>   server is through a web-based control
>   panel with a script execution window.
>   If supported by the hosting service
>   provider, the Database Publishing
>   Wizard can also directly upload
>   databases to servers located at the
>   shared hosting provider.
>
> Optionally, SQL Server Database
>   Publishing Wizard can integrate
>   directly into Visual Studio 2005
>   and/or Visual Web Developer 2005
>   allowing easy publishing of databases
>   from within the development
>   environment.

You can download the free tool [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en).